# Load a YAML files with a list of items of different structs

Tags: go, yaml

I have a YAML formatted like this:

```yaml
actions:
  - type: one
    onekey: value
  - type: two
    twokey: value
    foo: bar
```

and I would like to load it to a Go struct. I tried using [`mapstructurs`](https://github.com/mitchellh/mapstructure) with it's `DecodeHook` but I can't get it to work.

This is what I tried:

```golang
type Actions struct {
    actions []Action
}

type Action interface {
}

type One struct {
    Onekey string
}

type Two struct {
    Twokey string
    Foo    string
}

var actions Actions

func Load() {
...
    config := &mapstructure.DecoderConfig{
        DecodeHook: func(sourceType, destType reflect.Type, raw interface{}) (interface{}, error) {
            if fmt.Sprintf("%s", destType) == "Action" {
                var result Action

                switch raw.(map[string]interface{})["type"] {
                case "one":
                    result = One{}
                case "two":
                    result = Two{}
                }
                mapstructure.Decode(raw, &result)
                return result, nil
            }
            return raw, nil
        },
        Result: &actions,
    }
...
}
```

This is ugly and doesn't work either. I get:

```
panic: interface conversion: interface {} is map[interface {}]interface {}, not map[string]interface {}
```

First there is:

```golang
if fmt.Sprintf("%s", destType) == "Action"
```

which is hideous but the only way I got this part to work.

Then there is to read the list item and cast it to the right struct by the `type` key. Is there a way to make this work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In the end I went with this approach:

```golang
    config := &mapstructure.DecoderConfig{
        DecodeHook: func(sourceType, destType reflect.Type, raw interface{}) (interface{}, error) {
            var result Action
            if fmt.Sprintf("%s", destType) == "Action" {
                rawMap := raw.(map[interface{}]interface{})
                switch rawMap["type"] {
                case "one":
                    result = One{}
                case "two":
                    result = Two{}
                }

                mapstructure.Decode(raw, &result)
                return result, nil
            }
            return raw, nil
        },
        Result: &actions,
    }
```

I am only starting with Go so there could be a better way but this kinda solves the two issues I had.

Correction: I had to revert to `if fmt.Sprintf("%s", destType) == "Action"` since `reflect.TypeOf(result) == nil`

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at viper package : https://github.com/spf13/viper
It lets you read from toml, json yaml etc. files and then you can pass each configuration value to your struct.

Comment: I didn't quite realize how would viper help me with lists containing different types...